# Is it possible to create a second CSS transition when navigating to next page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im using a few CSS transition to face in content when my homepage load. I start the transition by using a javascript that adds a class to the element with the transitions. Im looking to dynamically load next set of pages, and wonder if I can set a new transition for the second pageload to "reverse" the transition with a fade out on  the elements on the current page.

Is this possible?

Comment: ["If your problem is with code you've written, you should include some."](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: There is no problem with code written, since im unsure on where to start.

Comment: "I start the transition by using a javascript that adds a class to the element with the transitions." Sounds like written code to me.

Comment: Yeah and if you read my post it states that i have a first part of what I achieve finished, and working without a problem. My question is how to start the second phase, and if its possible.

Comment: Your problem is you're trying to implement something new with existing code you have. This question is much harder answered, and an example harder demonstrated without a frame of reference of what you're already working with.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure to understand exactly, but you can :
-use jquery .animate() and then .queue() if you just need a visual fade

```
    $( '.activepage' ).animate({opacity: 0},200).removeClass('activepage').queue(function(){
    $( '#mysecondpage' ).addClass('activepage').animate({opacity: 1}, 200);
    $(this).dequeue();});
    };
```

please explain exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you are loading next page using ajax, you can fade out the main container and when the next page html comes from the ajax request, you can first replace the container html, and then execute the fade in on the same container.

If you are using jQuery for example, after the fadeOut finished, your container display will be "none", so when you add the new html, the user will see the empty container until you run the fadeIn and the whole container is showed up again with the effect :)

Comment: What if i have a container with two child containers, can i have them fade out with different transitions? I basically have three lines that draws up on pageload, and when loading next page i would like to draw them out the same way (in reverse of course) on the next pageload.

Comment: Sure, you can do it individually, but i do suggest you using jQuery fadeIn and fadeOut instead of css3 transition, it will be simple, you also have a callback for the fade transitions and you don't need to use many css lines of code. Just fadeOut and fadeIn what you want when you want. You don't need the jQuery UI plugin for this, the fades functions comes with jQuery :) Try to be clear on your code, you can have a function that receives a url where you serve the html for the page you want, that fades out the containers, adds the html and fades in them again, and use it for the home and pages.

Comment: Please let me know if you need some example code :)

Comment: Some sample code to fiddle around with would be great for my understanding :)